# Flyway parser fails while trying to create oracle packages from .sql script

Tags: oracle, flyway

I have got an SQL script stored in an .sql-file containing several statements like this:

```
create or replace package <schema>.custom_package is 
  procedure getReleaseEmployees(p_Cursor in out sys_refcursor, p_Role in string); 
end custom_package;
/

create or replace package <schema>.pck_account_monitoring is
  procedure checkAndLockOracleAccount;
end pck_account_monitoring;
/
<...some more packages following>
```

Running the script in an SqlDeveloper or PL/SQLDeveloper against my database works fine.
Now, when I'm trying to migrate via Flyway using the Java API, I'll get the following error message and Flyway's migration fails:

```
SQL State  : 42000
Error Code : 900
Message    : ORA-00900: Invalid SQL Statement
Location   : migrations/sql/V0_2__migration.sql
Line       : 6172
Statement  : end pck_account_monitoring
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.SqlScript.execute(SqlScript.java:117)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.resolver.sql.SqlMigrationExecutor.execute(SqlMigrationExecutor.java:71)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.doMigrate(DbMigrate.java:352)
```

If I try to put the first statement into a single line, i.e.

```
create or replace package quattro.custom_package is procedure getReleaseEmployees(p_Cursor in out sys_refcursor, p_Role in string); end custom_package;
/
<rest as before>
```

I'll get the same error message, but the parser now complains about the '/' symbol and the beginning of the next statement:

```
Error Code : 900
Message    : ORA-00900: Invalid SQL Statement
...
Line       : 6167
Statement  : /

create or replace package quattro.pck_account_monitoring is ...
```

Now, if I remove that first '/' as well, the migration will run (with warnings, though).
My schema will then correctly have compiled all the other packages except for the first one - even though every other package declaration is formatted like the first one was in my initial attempt! The first package (custom_package) however is still missing.

My Java class basically looks like the sample class from the Flyway homepage.

Does anyone have any idea what's going wrong here with the Flyway parser or can maybe provide me with a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(This is too long for a comment, therefore, I'm posting it as an answer)

FWIW, I cannot reproduce this (using the Flyway 3.2.1 command line tool); running this example script:

```
-- PACKAGES
create or replace package flyway_demo.custom_package is 
  procedure getReleaseEmployees(p_Cursor in out sys_refcursor, p_Role in string); 
end custom_package;
/

create or replace package flyway_demo.pck_account_monitoring is
  procedure checkAndLockOracleAccount;
end pck_account_monitoring;
/

create or replace package flyway_demo.logger
  authid definer
as
  -- TYPES
  type rec_param is record(
    name varchar2(255),
    val varchar2(4000));

  type tab_param is table of rec_param index by binary_integer;

  g_off constant number := 0;

  function is_number(p_str in varchar2)
      return boolean;
end logger;
/


create or replace package body flyway_demo.pck_account_monitoring is
  procedure checkAndLockOracleAccount is
  begin
    null;
  end;
end pck_account_monitoring;
/

create or replace package body flyway_demo.custom_package is 
  procedure getReleaseEmployees(p_Cursor in out sys_refcursor, p_Role in string)
  is
  begin
    open p_Cursor for select * from dual;
  end;
end custom_package;
/

create or replace package body flyway_demo.logger
as

  function is_number(p_str in varchar2) return boolean is
  begin
    return true;
  end;
end logger;
/
```

works perfectly fine. Can you please try it with this script and post your findings?

Comment: I have tried your script in my Java Application and you are right, it works fine. I still find it strange that my original script (still) does not work, but I solved that problem now by splitting the file into several files (i.e. one file for packages and one for package bodies, etc). Thank you.